# Question about an equation from LaTeX Search

Tags: math-mode

I was randomly looking in [LaTeX Search](http://www.latexsearch.com/) and I found the following formula:

`P\left( {E_n^{\left( d \right)} ,{\text{i}}{\text{.o}}{\text{.}}} \right) = 0\quad {\text{or}}\quad {\text{1}}`

In it there is this term:

`{\text{i}}{\text{.o}}{\text{.}}}`

Is there any reason for using 3 `\text` commands and not using a single one?

As these are equations from scientific papers it seems to me peculiar for someone to do this from ignorance so I can guess that there must be a reason.

Comment: I think that it is not that peculiar or, at least, probably not that unusual. Did you try compiling and comparing the two cases? I can't see any obvious visual difference. I wonder if this might be the product of an conversion tool e.g. from some other kind of mark-up or some other programme. (Not like this but when I convert Word forms to LaTeX, the code is fully of pointless things.)

Comment: I would guess there is no reason:-) `\left(d\right)` should be just `(d)` as well.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I saw that too, but the 3 `\text` commands were far more peculiar! @cfr I didn't know about conversion tools so it is interesting now that you mentioned it! Anyway thank you both very much. :)

Comment: @Adam You can only ping one person at once. (So you did not, in fact, ping me at all...)

Comment: @cfr Sorry about that! I will keep it in mind!

Comment: i've not been impressed with the quality of the material available from latex search.  many authors aren't aware of "best practices", some gui input tools create dreadful latex code, and the examples available from this web site appear not to have been edited with respect to the code, only to the appearance of the output.  admittedly, i'm pretty hard to satisfy in this respect, and this is only my personal opinion.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I only checked it out yesterday so I think that you are right although I didn't inspect a lot of formulas. Thought I will keep in mind what you say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just compare the two results and you will see that there is no difference. The letters are set in their own boxes as can be seen in the first (original) example, but I can't think of a use case for that.

The code looks as if it was not written manually. Maybe some conversation tool. I added a version on how I would type it. Just compare:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\begin{document}
\[P\left( {E_n^{\left( d \right)} ,{\text{i}}{\text{.o}}{\text{.}}} \right) = 0\quad {\text{or}}\quad {\text{1}}\]
\[P\Bigl(E_n^{(d)}, \text{i.o.}\Bigr) = 0 \quad \text{or} \quad 1\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent graphical analysis. Thank you for your answer!